# Salesforce lightning stop current playing Audio

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

we have a custom notification for the omni channel work assignment which plays an Audio sound, which works fine and as expected. Only issue we found is: If the agent uses the standard omni widget to accept the work , the custom component still plays the Audio,
I couldn't find anything (google) how to get and stop the current audio

onWorkAssigned the helper method calls the notify function which includes

```
  notify: function (component, event, helper) {
    var millis = new Date().getTime();
    var tag = "CU:" + millis;
    var myBod = "NEW VOICE CALL \n" + component.get("v.mycaller");
    console.log("is it2: " + component.get("v.mycaller"));
    const anAudio = new Audio($A.get("$Resource.ringtest"));
    anAudio.play();
    var n = new Notification("New Work", {
      icon: "/logos/Salesforce/LightningService/logo.png",
      tag: tag,
      body: myBod,
      requireInteraction: true,
    });
    n.onclick = function () {
      this.close();
      anAudio.pause();
      window.focus();
      helper.acceptWork(component, event, helper);
    };
  },
```

How can i stop the current playing sound with an eventhandler onWorkAccepted?

Answer (score 0):

Set the Audio on the helper, and you'll be able to access it across methods:

```
helper.anAudio = new Audio($A.get("$Resource.ringtest"));
```

...

```
helper.anAudio.pause();
```

You can also use the global `window` object.

Either way, keep in mind that window and helper are shared across all instances of your component, but will not necessarily be available across components.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox I have amended it and made the business aware, maybe i get a response and will(if works) mark this as best answer :-)

Comment: Somehow this threw an error
onWorkAccepted [ cannot read property of undefined (reading 'pause')

Would it work if i start a new audio playing and immediately stop the new audio
or will the original audio continue until it hits the 20 sec of playtime